# String.getBytes("UTF-8") is not platform independent?

Tags: java, string, encoding, utf-8, character-encoding

Am trying to hash my string and came up with the following code:

```
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.nio.charset.Charset;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.security.MessageDigest;
import sun.misc.BASE64Encoder;

public class JavaTest {
    public static void main (String[] args) throws UnsupportedEncodingException, NoSuchAlgorithmException {
        String rawString = "9498131529";
        System.out.println(Charset.defaultCharset());
        System.out.println(rawString);

        MessageDigest digest = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
        digest.update(rawString.getBytes("UTF-8")); 
        BASE64Encoder encoder = new BASE64Encoder();
        byte hashedBytes[] = (new String(digest.digest(), "UTF-8")).getBytes();
        System.out.println(encoder.encode(hashedBytes));
    }
}
```

I was under the impression that this piece of code should be platform independent, since when I try to get the bytes from the String I am specifying the encoding type "UTF-8".

But when I ran the code on my Mac, Dev environment and staging environment I got the following result:
***Mac***

```
MacRoman
9498131529
XElaLD8UPzE/P1sWDz8/Pw==
```

***Dev:***

```
US-ASCII
9498131529
XElaLD8UPzE/P1sWDz8/Pw==
```

***Staging***

```
UTF-8
9498131529
XElaLO+/vRTvv70x77+977+9WxYP77+977+977+9
```

My config:

***Mac***

```
> sw_vers
ProductName:    Mac OS X
ProductVersion: 10.9
BuildVersion:   13A603
```

***Dev***

```
> cat /proc/version
Linux version 2.6.21.7-2.fc8xen-ec2-v1.0  (gcc version 4.1.2 20070925 (Red Hat 4.1.2-33)) #2 SMP Tue Sep 1 10:04:29 EDT 2009
```

***Staging***

```
> cat /proc/version
Linux version 3.2.0-31-virtual (gcc version 4.6.3 (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.3-1ubuntu5) ) #50-Ubuntu SMP Fri Sep 7 16:36:36 UTC 2012
```

What am I missing here? Why is the hashing algorithm system independent? And I believe MD5 should be platform independent according to the specification. Am I wrong about my assumption?

Please let me know if you need any more details!

Comment: The step where you round-trip the digest to and from a string (`new String(digest.digest(), "UTF-8").getBytes()`) looks suspicious. (And unnecessary - you should probably base-64 the digest itself.) The digest might not, in fact, be valid UTF-8, and what you're seeing might be different decode error handling.

Comment: Actually, wait, that is probably exactly where things go wrong. `.getBytes()` without an argument encodes the string in the default charset, and MacRoman and US-ASCII might be similar enough to coincidentally give the same result. Using `.getBytes("UTF-8")` *should* get you identical behaviour everywhere, but it's still the wrong thing to do.

Comment: @millimoose Thanks for your inputs! :) I guess Stefan beat you to the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why the extra round trip through String? Even if you add "UTF-8" to getBytes() it would still be wrong because it would treat a raw byte array (the digest) as if it would be a UTF-8 encoded string.

Change the hashedBytes line to:

```
    byte hashedBytes[] = digest.digest();
```